# Passing a variable by value, printf doesn’t show the correct result

Tags: c

I'm a university student and in one of my exercises to train c programming I got stuck on an error with a print function. I used CLION which was great but now moved on into VS Code, because the teacher say it´s the most used in a professional environment. What are your thoughts on it?!

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "complex.h"


int main (){

    Complex x;
    

    inputNmbr(x);
    printNmbr(x);

  return 0;
}
```

complex.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
float r,i;
}Complex;

Complex inputNmbr(Complex x){

    printf("Input an imaginary number (R +/- I):\n");
    scanf("%f %f", &x.r, &x.i);

return x;
}


void printNmbr (Complex x){

 printf("Imaginary number: %.2f +/- %.2f\n", x.r, x.i);
}
```

Terminal

```
aluno@aluno-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Programação por objetos/P1/EX2$ ./main\
Input an imaginary number (R +/- I):
1 2
Imaginary number: 0.00 +/- 0.00
```

So the printf function always shows 0 0 and I´m not understanding the source of this error.

P.S. After being attacked about the C/C++ tag I´m posting the exercise (the reason why I put the both tags is related to this):

```
Write a module in C that allows working with complex numbers. 
Create the files complex.h and complex.cpp where you should implement the following functionalities:
The definition of data structure (Complex) to represent a complex number 
(r, i);
A function that reads a complex number;
A function that writes a complex number in the format: #.#+/-#.#i (where +/- depends on the sign of the imaginary part);
A function for each of the following operations:
Addition: a+bi+c+di=(a+c)+(b+d)i
Subtraction: a+bi-c+di=(a-c)+(b-d)i
Multiplication: (a+bi)*(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i
Division:
(a+bi) / (c+di)=((ac+bd)/(c^2+d^2))+((bc-ad)/(c^2+d^2))i
```

Comment: First, decide on a language.  Your file extension is `.cpp` which means C++, not C.  But you're using C functions.  You've then asked a question and tagged it with both languages.  Once you know which language you want to use, then you can read about how parameter passing _by value_ works (which is what you're currently doing) and then learn how to pass _by reference_ which can have different solutions depending on which language you use.

Comment: Don't tag `C++` if you're writing C code.

Comment: I am a bit confused as well. I´ll put the exercise on the post

Comment: You need to pass `x` into `inputNmbr` by reference, or use the value that `inputNmbr` is `return`ing. But you aren't doing either.

Comment: `inputNmbr` returns a value you never use, so the modifications it makes to its argument are lost upon return.

Comment: Look up "pass by value"

Comment: main is not using the return value.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going through all your execise, however, the problem of your incorrect `printf` is that your struct variable x is passed "by value" to the function `inputNmbr`. This means that when invoking it, a copy of your variable is created and put on the function stack, and even if you modify the value inside the function, the modification is not reflected in the original variable.
A solution can be to change the input parameter of `inputNmbr` function so to make it a pointer. For example:

```
    void inputNmbr(Complex * x){

        printf("Input an imaginary number (R +/- I):\n");
        scanf("%f %f", &(x->r), &(x->i));
   }
```

In this case, your main will be:

```
    int main (){

       Complex x;
        
       inputNmbr(&x);
       printNmbr(x);

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I´d never had a situation like this before so I was struggling to recognize where I was failing, guess I need to rewatch some old classes...

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest that you look into the difference of passing a variable "by value" and "by reference". The key point is all there. Comments above all suggested to look up this topic indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing this would be having in main:

```
Complex x = inputNmbr();
```

and in your fn definition:

```
Complex inputNmbr(){
    Complex a;
    printf("Input an imaginary number (R +/- I):\n");
    scanf("%f %f", &a.r, &a.i);

return a;
}
```

The choice of a "return" vs using pass by address to return is stylistic but may also depend on a standard depending on your professor.